Custom Teams app not visible for some meeting participants and even for the same user on some computers
Our custom Teams App is already published in the store and doing well, however some customers complain about some participants on their tenants not being able to see it.
They don't see the app and they don't even see the Apps icon in a Teams meeting where the host has added the app (and others can see it).
I was able to reproduce similar behaviour in its most bizarre manifestation:
On my computer, when I log in to Teams in an incognito window, using credentials of a test Tenant user, I cannot see Apps icon at all.
All my colleagues, however, also logging in in incognito window, using the same credentials, can see it! It's just mind boggling.
I would appreciate any hints regarding all the factors that can impact visibility of Apps icon, of seeing specific Apps shared in a meeting (within the same tenant and across different tenants).
Many thanks!
Apps visible, on one computer

Same account, different computer - no Apps!


Sometimes, browser settings or extensions can interfere with the functionality of Teams. Incognito mode can also have restrictions that might affect the visibility of certain features. It's worth trying different browsers or clearing the cache.
